# Cannot use an image when selecting a checkbox in IE8

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, checkbox, internet-explorer-8

When I click on an image inside a label to select/deselect a checkbox, it changes its state accordingly in Firefox and Chrome. However, in IE8, the checkbox never responds if I click on an image and only changes its state if I click on the text.

jsFiddle is here (click on the white box image before the text in IE):

http://jsfiddle.net/dzTMD/3/

Comment: Just an FYI, It seems to be giving me problems and I'm on FF15 on a Mac running Mountain Lion 10.8.1  Also, Is there supposed to be some JS code?  I don't see any in the JS box.

Comment: There's no js code. Since it happens with or without the javascript. (Although, I would add a javascript later.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem in IE8 but you can use background image within css instead of attaching it directly in html and this will work in IE. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kKVPj/1/) is fiddle with example

Answer (score 0):

put the input field inside the label tag
example:

```
<label>
    <input name="yn00" id="yn00_1" type="checkbox">
    <div class="indicator"></div>
    <span>My text for this label</span>
 </label>
```

all elements will work inside the label, your img aswell..
just remember to use opacity to hide the input field .
IE8 will not fire events on display:none or visibility:hidden elements